# Getting a discord id from username

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot that has a database of things and sometimes someone would want to see what things a different person has, this would be possible by using discord id, but I just don't was everyone sending their discord ids around.

I was trying to use something like this:

```
def get_user_id(name_en, tag_en, guild_id):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)  
  user = discord.utils.get(guild.members, name= "Atom" , discriminator= "#1803")
  print(user)
```

But that just outputs an empty message.

**So is there a way to get a discord id from a username?**

Also is this possible with making the discord bot in a different programming language? (if not possible in *discord.py*)

Thanks

Comment: The `discriminator` should only be the number without the `#`. discord.py already has a [`UserConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter) which converts usernames to users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Guild.get_member_named()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_member_named#discord.Guild.get_member_named)

> The name can have an optional discriminator argument, e.g. “Jake#0001” or “Jake” will both do the lookup. However the former will give a more precise result. Note that the discriminator must have all 4 digits for this to work.

```py
def get_user_id(name_en, tag_en, guild_id):
  guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)  
  user = guild.get_member_named(name_en)
  print(user)
```